# Piwik tracking other users

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to make my Piwik code track other users for my intranet site. So far I am able to track my own views, but if I were to have someone else access the site it would not track it below is my code that Piwik generated for me. I have also tried replacing the localhost with my URL but it still did not work.
Any feed back would be appreciated. Thank You.

```
<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(["setCookieDomain", "*.harold.local"]);
  _paq.push(["setDomains", ["*.harold.local"]]);
_paq.push(["deleteCookies"]);
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//localhost:8080/piwik/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 3]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
<noscript><p><img src="//localhost:8080/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=3&rec=3" style="border:0;" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

Comment: it's designed not to track, so this will be hard. but, you can set pwik cookies outside of pwik, provided you know which ones it's expecting. So, you make some exceptions using the interface, then inject those exceptions into pages of unsuspecting users using JS that runs on the site.

Comment: wait, isn't Piwik supposed to help track performance indicators such as visits?

Comment: yes, but it's not meant to disclose that to the site owner. you might be able to rip up the DB...

Comment: but from what I see I should be able to get a number count on visitors right?

Comment: visitors all have a little bit of storage in the cookie, which can hold a counter, so there might not be a counter you can reach...

Comment: so my code maybe correct and it can depend on the user's side is what your saying?